# Click one div in order to open only it's children and not other with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parent-child

So I tried obviously using $('this .classname') but it toggle closes the whole div.
I'm trying to have each div (image is placed) be clicked and only it's ul be opened.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="recipePicContainer">
        <div id="checkBoxes">
                <li class="recipe" id="recipe01"><label>Cocktail</label></li>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="recipePicContainer">
            <div class="checkBoxes">
                <li class="recipe" id="recipe02"><label>Main Dish</label></li>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="recipePicContainer">
            <div class="checkBoxes">
                <li class="recipe" id="recipe03"><label>Dessert</label></li>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var main = function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul').hide();
        $('.recipe').click(function () {
            $('.recipes').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. `<li>` is not a valid child of `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var main = function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.recipe').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('.recipes').toggle('slow');
      });
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.recipes{
  display:none;
}
.recipe{
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="recipePicContainer">
        <div id="checkBoxes">
        <ul class="recipe" id="recipe01">
          <li>Cocktail</li>
        </ul>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="recipePicContainer">
            <div class="checkBoxes">
              <ul class="recipe" id="recipe02">
                <li>Main Dish</li>
              </ul>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="recipePicContainer">
            <div class="checkBoxes">
              <ul class="recipe" id="recipe03">
                <li>Dessert</li>
               </ul>
                       <ul class="recipes">
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st use `$(this).next('.recipes')` since they are at the same level. So you could target the `recipes` next to `recipe` you clicked.

2nd use CSS to initially hide all recipes, because CSS is loaded much faster than script so you won't see that hidden drop-down flashing for 0.5 sec.

```
.recipes {
  display: none;
}
```

3rd `li` must have a parent of `ul` or `ol` or `menu` so do it this like:

```
  <ul class="recipe" id="recipe01">
    <li>Cocktail</li>
  </ul>
```

with css:

```
.recipe {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.recipe').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.recipes').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.recipes {
  display: none;
}

.recipe {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
      <ul class="recipe" id="recipe01">
        <li>Cocktail</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="recipes">
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
        <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div class="checkBoxes">
      <ul class="recipe" id="recipe02">
        <li>Main Dish</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="recipes">
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
        <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div class="checkBoxes">
      <ul class="recipe" id="recipe03">
        <li>Dessert</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="recipes">
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
        <li class="ingredient">
          <input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
        <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer includes invalid HTML.

Comment: Looks OK. Run it through the validator.

Comment: Wow Daniel, thank you so much for the time you put into this awesome answer! as you can see I'm struggling with this and want it eventually to be my ticket into becoming a Junior UI dev.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/jzwjh5jp/3/

```js
var main = function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.recipes').hide();
        $('.recipe').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.recipes {
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
    <ul class="recipe" id="recipe01"><li>Cocktail</li></ul>
    <ul class="recipes">
      <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
      <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
      <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
      <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
      <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="recipePicContainer">
     <div class="checkBoxes">
     <ul class="recipe" id="recipe02"><li>Main Dish</li></ul>
     <ul class="recipes">
        <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
        <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
        <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
        <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
        <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div class="checkBoxes">
      <ul class="recipe" id="recipe03"><li>Dessert</li></ul>
       <ul class="recipes">
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
            <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You answered by including invalid HTML which makes your answer invalid, too.

Comment: @Rob I overlook it. I made the changes.

Comment: Thanx Shiladitya! very elegant!